# Why graphene's substrate is important

Tags: solid-state-physics, spectroscopy, electronic-band-theory, graphene

I just have some feelings that somehow it is important what specific subtrate is used to grow graphene monolayer on. Some substrates are better, another ones are not so good. But I cannot completely understand in what sense they are good or bad. If someone could enlighten this moment for me I would be really greateful.

It is not about graphene at all. For exmaple, one prefers sapphire substrate for another 2D material, namely tungsten disulphide (WS2). So what is so special about substrates for 2D materials?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The usual experimental zeroth order problem is that the lattice constants have to match fairly well, otherwise there will be a strain in the deposited film which introduces defects and periodic modulations. That will certainly mess up your electronic and phonon properties very considerably (sometimes that, of course, is the whole point, because the physics of these meta-lattices can be quite fascinating). Did you compare the lattice constants of these materials?

Comment: Another issue is that some materials bond well to each other. For example, gold bonds poorly to SiO2. However, gold sticks to nickel and nickel sticks to SiO2, so depositing a layer of nickel and then gold works better.

Comment: I've just learnt that the lattice constant of WS2-monolayer is a=3.146 angstroms, and the corresponding lattice parameter of sapphire (Al2O3) is a=4.758 angstroms. So, is it a great difference? What is the comparison scale according to which one can say that there is a good matching between lattices or not?

Comment: As for gold, nickel and quartz, their lattice constants are following: a(Au)=4.078, a(Ni)=3.524, a(SiO2)=4.9138. It was said that gold bonds poorly to SiO2, however, nickel sticks to SiO2. But the difference between lattice parameters for Au-SiO2 is less than for Ni-SiO2. So, I do not understand, why Nickel sticks to SiO2 better than gold.

Comment: In the case of gold, it was chemistry, not lattice constants.

Comment: mmesser314, what do you mean?